# html5 Can I somehow disable adblock for vote-modal-window? (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, adblock

I have a problem on my website, where adblock is removing all text from my vote-modal-window (Bootstrap). When I click on the button, it just shows me blank window without text. I found out it is a problem with adblock. Heres the code:

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vote-modal"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i>
HLASUJ</a>
</li>



<div class="modal fade" id="vote-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-green multiple-shadow"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> HLASUJ</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ads-card">
            <h2>
                <span class="text-green">Hlasuj pro náš server!</span>
                <br>
                <small>Pomoz serveru a získej zajímavé odměny!</small>
            </h2>
            <ul style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 25px;">
                <li>
         <a class="text-green" href="https://czech-craft.eu/server/mythiaproject/">Czech-craft </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="text-green" href="https://craftlist.org/mythiaproject">Craftlist </a>
                </li>
                <li>
       <a class="text-green" href="https://minecraftservery.eu/server/182">Minecraft Servery </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zavřít</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem, or should I just try to redo the whole thing? :)
Thanks in advance
Jacob

Comment: It may be to do with the `ads-card` class. I'm unsure of the specifics behind the adblockers blocking logic. But having the word "ad" (short for advertisement) on the `div`, maybe why the text is being suppressed.

Comment: I had a bit more of a snoop... Adblock actually has a public blacklist of CSS classes that it searches for to hide elements. `ads-card` is on that list. reference: https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt

Comment: Thanks guys, it solved the problem. It didn't even hit my mind it could be something with this class.